How do I auto fill an empty value of an object in an array with an object that matches from another array in JS?
I've been trying to create a table that auto fill empty fields depending of the previous information provided but I don't know how to make it possible, do you have any idea?
Here's an example of an array of fruits and a second array that contains the answer I want to apply if it match.
//The 'doYouLike' field is what I'm trying to fill out

const CheckingFruits = () => {
  var fruits = [
    { name: 'orange', color: 'orange', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'pinneaple', color: 'yellow', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'apple', color: 'red', doYouLike: '' },
  ];

//Taking this info I want to fill it out, but I don't know the logic to apply it
   const doILke = [
    { name: 'orange', answer: 'yes' },
    { name: 'banana', answer: 'no' },
    { name: 'pinneaple', answer: 'no' },
    { name: 'apple', answer: 'yes' },
  ];

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Color</th>
          <th>Do you like?</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {fruits.map((fruit, id) => (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{fruit.name}</td>
            <td>{fruit.color}</td>
      //This is were I would like to show the answer
            <td>{fruit.doYouLike}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

CheckingFruits()

I've been trying several days looking for an answer in youtube or forums but without success.
I've just found how to find one value:
function filterByOneFruit(fruit, fruitName) {
    return fruit.filter((item) => item.name=== name);

const foundTheFruit= filterByOneFruit(
    fruits,'apple'
);

//Output: { name: 'apple', color: 'red', doYouLike: '' }

but I don't know how to find and change multiple values at the same time
I really apreciate if you can help me.

filter() returns an array of all the items that match the condition. So that can't be the output you're getting.

If you want to change the values, loop over the result and assign to the properties. E.g. filterByOneFruit(fruits, 'apple').forEach(item => item.doYouLike = true)



const fruits = [{
    name: 'orange',
    color: 'orange',
    doYouLike: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'banana',
    color: 'yellow',
    doYouLike: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'pinneaple',
    color: 'yellow',
    doYouLike: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red',
    doYouLike: ''
  },
];

const doILike = [{
    name: 'orange',
    answer: 'yes'
  },
  {
    name: 'banana',
    answer: 'no'
  },
  {
    name: 'pinneaple',
    answer: 'no'
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    answer: 'yes'
  },
];

fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
  const foundFruit = doILike.find((item) => item.name === fruit.name);
  if (foundFruit) {
    fruit.doYouLike = foundFruit.answer;
  }
});

const tableBody = document.querySelector('#fruitTable tbody'); // get table body


fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
  const row = document.createElement('tr'); //Create table rows for each fruit

  const nameCell = document.createElement('td');
  nameCell.textContent = fruit.name;
  row.appendChild(nameCell);

  const colorCell = document.createElement('td');
  colorCell.textContent = fruit.color; // set fruit color
  row.appendChild(colorCell);

  const likeCell = document.createElement('td');
  likeCell.textContent = fruit.doYouLike; // set fruit doYouLik
  row.appendChild(likeCell);

  tableBody.appendChild(row); // add row to body
});
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Fruit </h1>
  <table id="fruitTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Do you like?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>




wooow, no words about it,  this is a complete example about my question, very grateful with you my friend.

Happy to help appreciate if you can mark it as correct answer and give an upvote for the contribution :-)

Of course my friend, I didn't know how to do it but just found it.

prefer to use js table method .inssertRowl() and .inssertCell()  -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

I hadn't heard about that method @MisterJojo thank you, I'll be looking the documentation about how to apply it.

Loop over the fruits array. For each fruit, search for the corresponding fruit in the doILike array, and copy its answer property.


var fruits = [
    { name: 'orange', color: 'orange', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'pinneaple', color: 'yellow', doYouLike: '' },
    { name: 'apple', color: 'red', doYouLike: '' },
  ];

//Taking this info I want to fill it out, but I don't know the logic to apply it
const doILike = [
    { name: 'orange', answer: 'yes' },
    { name: 'banana', answer: 'no' },
    { name: 'pinneaple', answer: 'no' },
    { name: 'apple', answer: 'yes' },
  ];
  
fruits.forEach(f => 
    f.doYouLike = doILike.find(l => l.name == f.name)?.answer || ''
);

console.log(fruits);




thanks it helped me to understand a bit how to use forEach, I'll be looking more about it.
